ScrollView can not scroll in ConstraintLayout
A child ScrollView is under a parent ConstraintLayout.
It can not scroll.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top_in_root_view_layer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_dislpay"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_sheet_dialog_bg"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_outside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_outside"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_top_in_root_view_layer"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="11:1"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_left_outside"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.01"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_right_outside"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.56"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:background="@color/light_white"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_outside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_outside"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_title"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        ... check the following ...
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


#Inside the ScrollView, there is another ConstraintLayout
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:background="@color/light_white"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_outside"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_outside"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_title"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_left_item_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.025"/>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical_right_item_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.975"/>


            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_day_night_mode_left"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.05"/>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline_day_night_mode_right"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95"/>
            <View
                android:id="@+id/day_night_mode_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/display_setting_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4.5:1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_mode_auto"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Auto"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_day_night_mode_left"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/display_mode_day"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_mode_day"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Day"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/display_mode_auto"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_mode_night"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Night"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/display_mode_day"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_day_night_mode_right"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/instant_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="instant message"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.09"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/day_night_mode_bg"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/instant_message_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/display_setting_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instant_message"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4.5:1"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_tv"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="tv"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instant_message_bg"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_day_night_mode_left"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/instant_message_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/instant_message_bg"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/display_time"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="time"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/display_tv"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/instant_message_bg"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/instant_message_bg"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/static_data"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="static data"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.09"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/instant_message_bg"/>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/static_data_bg"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/display_setting_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guideline_vertical_right_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline_vertical_left_item_bg"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/static_data"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4.5:1"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>


# XML UI looks like this
p.s. For the scrollView, if I set the attributes like the following, when it runs on the phone, the whole scrolloView will vanish.
android:layout_height="0dp" ,
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

can you share the code of the guideline?

I don't know the code of guidelines, so I use the parent as a constraint, and scrolling works fine. I think the issue is not in a ScrollView but in the constraints. Please review your constraint or share the guideline code.

@Laser ,Prem Danej
I've uplod the whole code.
Please help me check what's going on? thanks.

Set layout_height to 0dp:
android:layout_height="0dp"

You must also ensure that the content inside the ScrollView is large enough to require scrolling. If the inner ConstraintLayout (or its children) doesn't have enough height, the ScrollView won't scroll.

The issue with your ConstraintLayout inside of your ScrollView is that you can change the ConstraintLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" instance of android:layout_height="match_parent"
If the issue is the same then change to the NestedScrollViwe instance of ScrollView
